# Ringtones set to high volume when Received SMS from particular Number

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, avsystemcontroller

I am working on one iOS app which have a requirement that if phone received sms from particular number so set ringtones volume to loud.

I know how to increase or decrease the volume which most likely to this.

```
[[AVSystemController sharedAVSystemController] setVolumeTo:10.0 forCategory:@"Ringtone"];
```

But how could i check that sms received from particular number even application is  closed?

Comment: This is not possible, the iOS SDK does not allows you to detect the receivement of SMS.

Comment: i think its possible because i saw app using UISharedApplication delegates for checking the sms pin received. so maybe there could any way:) just  hope  also reading iOS security compliance. But i am also have doubt.

Comment: No it is not possible to read the SMS inbox.